# How to start a new project with the latest version of AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, templates, scaffolding, angularjs-templates

What's the best way to start a new project with the latest version of AngularJS (currently 1.7.2)?

The [official documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/misc/started) suggests to clone the [Seed App project template](https://github.com/angular/angular-seed), but that uses the old `1.5.11` version on AngularJS.

Even yarn AngularJS starter kit (`yarn create angular-app my-app`) seem to include deprecated packages and then fails at the node-sass postinstall script.

I know new projects should use the [latest version of Angular](https://angular.io/), but this is only for educational purposes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a minimalist AngularJS project with [Yarn](https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/) by running:

```
yarn init
yarn add angular
yarn add angular-route
yarn add gulp --dev
yarn add gulp-concat --dev
```

and then you will have to create a `gulpfile.js` with the build task.

Alternatively, you can start from [angularjs-starter-kit](https://github.com/lackovic/angularjs-starter-kit).

Answer (score 2):

1) Clone the [Seed App project template](https://github.com/angular/angular-seed);

2) Change the dependencies in `bower.json` to:

```
"angular": "1.7.x",
"angular-route": "1.7.x",
"angular-loader": "1.7.x",
"angular-mocks": "1.7.x",
```